# Facebook like button on click

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any way to listen on click facebook like button in api version v1.12 according to this article:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

Comment: as you can read in the article, you can use webhooks

Comment: yeah that's right, but question was about listening on this event on frontend of my application. Thanks anyway

Comment: that is not possible anymore then. why would you need that anyway?

Comment: business requirements :>)

Comment: that does not answer my question ;) - and it´s a pretty important question, a correct answer depends on it.

Comment: I need to track like button to give user an access to wifi.

Comment: that´s why i asked...because it´s not allowed to require likes for anything. you need to read the platform policy. here is a link about the relevant part: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Comment: "Don’t incentivize people to like a Page, or give the impression that liking a Page will be rewarded"

Comment: thanks man, didn't realized that it's forbidden. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to track facebook like event legally. `edge.create` event was deprecated (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/)

In the other hand, trying to track facebook like and then give user something is not allowed according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Thanks luschn for comments